# Android progress bar steadily increase over fixed time period

Tags: android

I am trying to get a progress bar to flow from 0 to 100% at a steady rate over a fixed period of time, for example 20 seconds. When the 20 seconds are up, I will run a runnable then repeat this process and so on... What is my best way of approaching this? I could use a Handler that runs every 50ms and moves the progress bar by a certain percentage. Is this the best way or would this use large amounts of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use a `Handler` and call `setProgress` to whatever you need to. `Handler` will not use a large amount of memory. This is typically how it's done.